# How to increase MySQL buffer length?

Tags: mysql

One of our WordPress plugins require that we increase MySQL buffer length. I cannot find anything on Stackoverflow on clearly how to do this. We are running a VPS with CentOS 7. Any idea how we can increase this value?

Comment: By changing the configuration. See the documentation. Off topic.

Comment: There are dozens of buffers within MySQL, all with different purposes. You need to establish which one you need to change. There are lots of questions around how to change certain settings here on SO. If you know the name of the variable, then just substitute the name of the server variable into any of those solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As of MySQL 5.6.2, the innodb_change_buffer_max_size configuration
>   option allows you to configure the maximum size of the change buffer
>   as a percentage of the total size of the buffer pool. By default,
>   innodb_change_buffer_max_size is set to 25. The maximum setting is 50.
>
> You might consider increasing innodb_change_buffer_max_size on a MySQL
>   server with heavy insert, update, and delete activity, where change
>   buffer merging does not keep pace with new change buffer entries,
>   causing the change buffer to reach its maximum size limit.
>
> You might consider decreasing innodb_change_buffer_max_size on a MySQL
>   server with static data used for reporting, or if the change buffer
>   consumes too much of the memory space that is shared with the buffer
>   pool, causing pages to age out of the buffer pool sooner than desired.
>
> Test different settings with a representative workload to determine an
>   optimal configuration. The innodb_change_buffer_max_size setting is
>   dynamic, which allows you modify the setting without restarting the
>   server.

you should read this it might help.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-change-buffer-maximum-size.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the buffer size in server configuration. Refer steps at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-change-buffer-maximum-size.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_change_buffer_max_size

Comment: yup. for other engine its also possible. you will have to change respective flags. open the second link, it has all the flags listed.